Why do some Whisper quests have a fire icon in Helltides
In Season 4 of the game the Helltides have been overhauled. Now I can see some Tree of Whisper quests which are marked with a fire icon.

What is the fire symbol telling me about these Tree of Whisper quests?

I'm not 100% sure but I think they are just Helltide specific. I.e. Their objectives focus on completing things only possible within a helltide zone.

When running Helltides tonight, I noticed that these Tree of Whisper quests are Helltide specific as mentioned in the comments.

This quest popped for me, and it's clear that it can only be completed during a Helltide, as it's collecting Cinders.

I think, the fire icon symbol indicates that these are high-priority or time-sensitive missions, offering greater challenges or rewards.
